# How to create a bitmap from a Device Context?

Tags: c#, bitmap, pinvoke, gdi

I have been drawing into a Device Context, and now I want to be able to save the contents of the device context to an image. If saving directly from the bitmap is not the best way then how can I get from the device context to the bitmap? I am trying to do this in C#.

EDIT: Thanks to SeriesOne I was able to modify his code to save a DC into a BMP. Here is how I changed it:

```
  Rectangle bmpRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480);
                   // Create a bitmap
                   using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpRect.Width, bmpRect.Height))
                   {
                       Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromHdc(hdcScreen);
                       bmp.Save("C:\\MyBitmap.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                       gfx.Dispose();
                   }
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far and more clearly explain what you want to further do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Set the size/location of your bitmap rectangle.    
Rectangle bmpRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480);
    // Create a bitmap
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpRect.Width, bmpRect.Height))
    {
        // Create a graphics context to draw to your bitmap.
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            //Do some cool drawing stuff here
            gfx.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, bmpRect);
        }

        //and save it!
        bmp.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\MyBitmap.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
```

This works well if you want to save your bitmap as a file. this uses GDI+ (which is software rendered, mostly), so performance isn't much of an issue since you are rendering to a static file.

You could also use this to create an off-screen graphics buffer when rendering controls. In this case, you just remove the save statement, and write the bitmap content to the controls device context.

Comment: I ended up using this and modified it.

Comment: @user1632018, Cool, glad I could help! I see in your example, you have decided to remove the using statement and go with creating the Graphics instance, and then disposing it (.Dispose()) when you're done. Just FYI, the using statement does this for you, automatically. In fact, you can't even use a using statement unless the object you're "using" implements IDisposable.